# ошибка компиляции gcc при использовании статик

Tags: gcc, static

требуется компилировать программу со следующими параметрами

> `gcc -x c -std=c2x -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -DONLINE_JUDGE -Wl,-s,-static,-lm,--stack=67108864 -o %1.exe %1`

в windows всё нормально.
а вот в linux (ubunta) выдаётся ошибка

> /usr/bin/ld: неизвестный параметр «--stack=67108864»

и

> /usr/bin/ld: невозможно найти -lgcc_s
>
> /usr/bin/ld: невозможно найти -lgcc_s

со стеком я понял.

а вот со статическими библиотеками так и не нашёл решения, что и откуда ещё нужно скачать?
установлено следующее

```
vlad@vlad-Linux:~$ dpkg -l | grep gcc<br>
ii gcc 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 amd64 GNU C compiler<br>
ii gcc-10-base:amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)<br>
ii gcc-9 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GNU C compiler<br>
ii gcc-9-base:amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)<br>
ii gcc-9-multilib 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GNU C compiler (multilib support)<br>
ii gcc-multilib 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 amd64 GNU C compiler (multilib files)<br>
ii lib32gcc-9-dev 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GCC support library (32 bit development files)<br>
ii lib32gcc-s1 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GCC support library (32 bit Version)<br>
ii libgcc-9-dev:amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GCC support library (development files)<br>
ii libgcc-s1:amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GCC support library<br>
ii libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- CPPU helper library<br>
ii libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- "purpose environment" helper<br>
ii libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- SAL helpers for C++ library<br>
ii libx32gcc-9-dev 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GCC support library (x32 development files)<br>
ii libx32gcc-s1 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 GCC support library (x32)
```

вот ещё немного, что я накопал
gcc ищет libgcc_s.a,
 но у нас есть только:

```
vlad@vlad-Linux:~/C/test$ locate libgcc_s<br>
/snap/core18/2128/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/snap/core18/2128/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/snap/core18/2246/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/snap/core18/2246/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgcc_s.so<br>
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so<br>
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/snap/snapd/13640/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so<br>
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/32/libgcc_s.so<br>
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/x32/libgcc_s.so<br>
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1<br>
/usr/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Comment: если кратко, то чтобы слинковать статический бинарник, надо передавать `-static` компилятору, а не линкеру т.е. просто `-static`, а не как часть ключа `-Wl`… Про то что размер стека процесса регулируется `ulimit`'ом, я так понимаю, уже узнал… но скорей всего все эти ключи линкера тебе всё равно не нужны, так что вполне достаточно будет ограничиться чем-то таким: `gcc -x c -std=c2x -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -DONLINE_JUDGE -lm -o foo foo.c`

Comment: Задам вопрос так. С требуемыми ключами gcc хочет наличие статических библиотек в частности libgcc_s.a. В gcc для windows они есть, то что я установил  в linux их не содержит. Вопрос как доустоновить статические стандартные библиотеки в linux? Я принципиально хочу понять этот момент, что я делаю не так на ровном месте? Решение - отказаться от статики, не есть решение моего вопроса.

Comment: Если статическая линковка нужна то, как я выше написал, ключ `-static` надо передавать не нижележащему линкеру, а самому компилятору т.е. **не** `gcc … -Wl,…-static…`, а просто `gcc … -static`. В первом случае -static считывается `ld` не как «создать статический бинарник», а как «все библиотеки которые будут указаны дальше линковать статически»… Я не настолько хорошо знаю потроха `gcc`, чтобы сказать зачем именно нужна `libgcc_s`, но при статической линковке она не используется… «вместо» неё (наряду с другими изменениями) у меня линкуется `libgcc_eh`…

Comment: Почему это работает с `mingw` я тоже сказать не могу — подозреваю, что это просто какой-то грязный хак или некорректное использование… а может это и законное средство...

Comment: ЗЫ: посмотрел, что под капотом в `w64-mingw32`: это хак, который просто «прокатывает» т.к. набор библиотек и включаемых объектников рантайма для динамической и статической линковки идентичен

Comment: ура работает: gcc -x c -std=c2x -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -DONLINE_JUDGE -static -Wl,-s,-lm -o $2 $1 Спасибо.